# problem with modifying a value in an object

Tags: c++, function, object, sfml

sorry but english is not my native language so if the question is not clear let me know.
So i have a cell object, a map struct and a map manager; the important bit are these:

Cell.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
enum class CellState
{
    selected,
    notSelected,
    selectable
};

struct Cell : sf::RectangleShape
{
private:
    CellState m_state = CellState::notSelected;

public:

    Cell(const CellState& state)
        : m_state(state)
    {
    }
    Cell()
    {
        m_state = CellState::notSelected;
    }


    void setCellState(CellState state)
    {
        m_state = state;
    }

};
```

Map.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Cell.hpp"

struct Map
{
private:
    
    static const int m_sizeX = 8;
    static const int m_sizeY = 8;
    Cell m_map[m_sizeX][m_sizeY];
public:
    static const int m_cellSize = 64;
    Map()
    {
        Cell cell(CellState::notSelected);
        for (size_t y = 0; y < m_sizeY; y++)
        {
            for (size_t x = 0; x < m_sizeX; x++)
            {
                m_map[x][y] = cell;
            }
        }
    }

    bool isValidCoord(sf::Vector2i cellCoord)
    {
        if (cellCoord.x < 0 || cellCoord.y < 0 || cellCoord.x > m_sizeX - 1 || cellCoord.y > m_sizeY - 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    Cell getCellAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return m_map[x][y];
    }
};
```

mapManager.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Map.hpp"

class MapManager
{
public:

    MapManager();

    void drawMap(sf::RenderWindow &window);

    sf::Vector2i mouseCoordToGridCoord(sf::Vector2i mouseCoord);

    void selectCell(sf::Vector2i cellCoord);
    void deselectCell(sf::Vector2i cellCoord);

    bool isValidCoord(sf::Vector2i cellCoord);

    sf::Vector2i getLastSelectedCell();

private:

    sf::Vector2i m_lastSelectedCell;

public:
    Map map;

};
```

mapManager.cpp

```cpp
#include "headers\map\MapManager.hpp"

MapManager::MapManager()
{
}

void MapManager::drawMap(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    for (size_t y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            Cell cell = map.getCellAt(x, y);
            switch (cell.getCellState())
            {
            case CellState::selected:
            {
                cell.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
            }break;

            case CellState::notSelected:
            {
                cell.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
            }break;

            }

            cell.setPosition(map.m_cellSize * x, map.m_cellSize * y);
            window.draw(cell);
        }
    }
}

sf::Vector2i MapManager::mouseCoordToGridCoord(sf::Vector2i mouseCoord)
{
    return mouseCoord / map.m_cellSize;
}

void MapManager::selectCell(sf::Vector2i cellCoord)
{
    map.getCellAt(cellCoord).setCellState(CellState::selected);
    m_lastSelectedCell = cellCoord;
}

void MapManager::deselectCell(sf::Vector2i cellCoord)
{
    map.getCellAt(cellCoord).setCellState(CellState::notSelected);
}

bool MapManager::isValidCoord(sf::Vector2i cellCoord)
{
    return map.isValidCoord(cellCoord);
}

sf::Vector2i MapManager::getLastSelectedCell()
{
    return m_lastSelectedCell;
}
```

what i want is that when i click a cell the cell turns yellow but for some reason even if
`map.getCellAt(cellCoord).setCellState(CellState::selected);`
seems to change the value of `m_state` it doesn't

i tried using the debugger to understand why but i can't wrap my head around the why it happens.
i hope that what i wrote is clear.

Comment: `getCellAt` returns a `Cell` by value, so you're operating on a copy of the original. You probably want to return a reference instead.

Comment: In this code `Cell cell = map.getCellAt(x, y);` the variable `cell` holds a **copy** of the cell in the map. It's not the same cell. So you change `cell` and it has no effect at all on the map. This is how C++ works but it surprises many beginners. As the comment above says, one option is to use *references*.

Comment: Note that even if `getCellAt` returned a reference, `Cell cell = ...;` would make a copy anyway. You'd need `Cell& cell = ...;` to get the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the return type of getCellAt:

```
Cell& getCellAt(int x, int y)
{
    return m_map[x][y];
}
```

This returns a reference to the cell instead of a copy of it.

Comment: You also have to change the variable you assign to, to be a reference as well. By itself the change above is not sufficient,